# Speech to Text program using Android and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying to use JavaScript in my Android code for Speech to Text.

Below is the code :

### CODE INFORMATION

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

function startDictation() {
         // document.getElementById("objectText").innerHTML = window+"";
        //  android.showToast(window+"");
          if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition')) {
                    document.getElementById('transcript').value = "";
                    document.getElementById('transcript').placeholder = "Listening...";

                    recognition.continuous = false
                    recognition.interimResults = false

                    //Change the locale here
                    recognition.lang = "en-IN";
                    recognition.start();

                    recognition.onresult = function(e) {
                              document.getElementById('transcript').value = e.results[0][0].transcript;
                              recognition.stop();

                              //Handle the text response
                              var textContent = document.getElementById('transcript').value;
                              console.log(textContent);

                              //Here textContent is output of your speech in text format
                    };

                    recognition.onend = function() {
                              recognition.stop();
                              document.getElementById('transcript').placeholder = "Speak";
                    };

                    recognition.onerror = function(e) {
                              recognition.stop();
                              document.getElementById('transcript').value = "No speech detected";
                              document.getElementById('transcript').placeholder = "Speak";
                    }
          } else {
                    document.getElementById('transcript').value = "Speech recognition not supported"
                    document.getElementById('transcript').placeholder = "Speak";
          }
}


</script>
```

## ERROR

Error occurs here:

```
if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition'))`
```

results in `false`

This line does not work. What can be done to solve this ?